# I am using recreate() to refresh but why does it double refresh?

Tags: android, page-refresh

I am using recreate and refresh() to refresh page every minute but it double refreshes. First refresh is after 1minute, and the next refresh is after 2 sec first refresh.

i have tried changing the code inside refresh but didnt work.

```
private void loadalltrolley(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,   PRODUCT_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray products = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i =0;i<products.length();i++){
                            JSONObject productObject = products.getJSONObject(i);
                            String gate_no = productObject.getString("gate_no");
                            String dock_name = productObject.getString("dock_name");
                            String dock_desc = productObject.getString("dock_desc") ;
                            int flight_arrival = productObject.getInt("flight_arrival");
                            int trolley_count = productObject.getInt("trolley_count");

                            Product product = new Product(gate_no,dock_name,dock_desc,flight_arrival,trolley_count);
                            allterminalList.add(product);




                        }



                        allterminaladapter = new ProductAdapter(alert.this,allterminalList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(allterminaladapter);
                        int count = allterminaladapter.getItemCount();
                        int i =0;



                        if (count>0)
                        {
                            displayNotification();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(alert.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);


    refresh(60000);


}


public void refresh(int milliseconds){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recreate();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,milliseconds);
}
```

I want it to refresh 1 time only and not double refresh. I want to refresh the application after 1minute only.

Comment: Is it possible that `refresh` is called twice? Can you verify this?

Comment: i only have refresh once, which is in the method loadalltrolley()

Comment: Yes, but it's possible that `loadalltrolley` is triggered twice

Comment: ummm how? i only called it once....

Comment: if(i==0)
                {
                    allterminalList.clear();
                    loadalltrolley();
                }
                else if(i==1)
                {
                    allterminalList.clear();
                    loadt1trolley();
                }

Comment: i am using spinner drop down list and if i click on position 0, it will call that method loadalltrolley

Comment: Can you first try debugging and logging?

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: You can try putting this inside your `run()` : `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`

Comment: still the same, refreshes twice. First refresh after 1minute, 2nd refresh after 2sec of first refresh

Comment: but the refresh only applies for sometimes